MS D365 Performance Testing with Jmeter - Query
Recently started a poc for D365 performance testing, with JMeter, since i have limitation (proxy configuration in my machine - ) to record with HTTP recorder / bzt correlation record, I have used Blazemeter chrome plug in to capturerecord.
I have managed to correlate most of the dynamic value with login and authentication but except below values
`wctx = LoginOptions=3&estsredirect=2&estsrequest=<encoded string valueS>`

Anyone come across this issue?

Also When i tried to record using JMeter in local machine for the D365 application getting below error:

`java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:279)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:269)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:175)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.LaxGZIPInputStream.<init>(LaxGZIPInputStream.java:42)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.lambda$static$0(HTTPHC4Impl.java:205)
    at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.initWrapper(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:51)
    at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.read(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:63)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1950)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:475)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:678)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1311)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:251)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.correlation.core.proxy.CorrelationProxy.run(CorrelationProxy.java:57)`

Any help or inputs really appreciate your support
I have tried to capture /record multiple times and tried to record using other tool (Neoload) but can't be able to find these values.. lookinto this website if any solution has been posted


For wctx - just extract it from the previous response, it contains federation context
For EOF exception - you can raise a ticket in the Correlation Recorder Plugin's repository. If you're a BlazeMeter customer you can also open a BlazeMeter support ticket especially if recording using "normal" HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is successful, it might speed the things up

